# How to display multiple real time data obtained from the sensor through serial port in different text box?

Tags: c#

I am using DHT11 sensors in Arduino Mega 2560. There are two types of data that I want to collect, humidity and temperature. Next, I wish to display these two data into the different text boxes of GUI C#. But so far I am only able to display the data into the same text box.[Coding use for the C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AomEb.jpg)

[My Arduino coding. Two floats; h and t but I wish to split it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xebmd.jpg)

Comment: What does the output look like? Is there anything delimiting the two values, or are they of a fixed length?

Comment: Also, for future reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I honestly believe you'd get more if posting at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this could have been a simple comment, since you didn't really answer the question ...

Comment: I don't have enough rep =D I can only comment my own answers

Comment: Actually the question is just poorly worded and not enough information was supplied. What the OP was really asking was how to split the returned value to display in separate fields.

Comment: That's why I sent him to the Arduino Stack Exchange site, since I believe it's more on how to get the datas rather than displaying it. Or it can be something as simple as value1 + '#' + value2 used with Split(str, '#'), then it's really poorly worded